# Erro em formatação de string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Estou tentando personalizar o espaçamento usado numa *string* formatada, centralizar pra ficar bem visual entre as linhas. O programa está me retornando erro de valor.

Segue o código:

```
def titulo(msg):
  tam = len(msg) + 4
  print('=' * tam)
  print(f'{msg:^tam}')
  print('=' * tam)

titulo('TRATAMENTO DE ERROS E EXCESSÕES')
```

O Python não aceita uma variável inteira como parâmetro pra usar no espaçamento? No caso a variável `tam`.

Qual seria a maneira correta pra centralizar exatamente entre as linhas, levando em consideração o tamanho delas e da própria mensagem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você tem uma variável em um local que espera um literal precisa dizer que é uma variável, então da mesma forma que faz para dizer que é uma expressão a ser interpolada e não um literal de texto, tem que dizer que ali é uma expressão, esta forma é o uso das chaves nessa parte também, portanto pode usar chaves aninhadas:

```
def titulo(msg):
  tam = len(msg) + 4
  print('=' * tam)
  print(f'{msg:^{tam}}')
  print('=' * tam)

titulo('TRATAMENTO DE ERROS E EXCESSÕES')
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/EBlFm5). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/FStringVariablepy). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/String/FStringVariable.py).